# "KeyError: 'partitioner' " is thrown when Tensorflow 2.2 loads a 2.1 model that has NumericColumn

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I built a functional model in Tensorflow 2.1 that uses a `NumericColumn` and saved it in the `h5` format.

It loads well in 2.1, but in 2.2 it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_code.py", line 75, in _load_model_from_path
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 184, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 178, in load_model_from_hdf5
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/model_config.py", line 55, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 109, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File ".venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 373, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File ".venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 987, in from_config
    config, custom_objects)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 2019, in reconstruct_from_config
    process_layer(layer_data)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 2001, in process_layer
    layer = deserialize_layer(layer_data, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 109, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File ".venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 373, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File ".venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py", line 473, in from_config
    config['partitioner'], custom_objects)
KeyError: 'partitioner'
```

An unknown key `partitioner` is expected in the layer's `config`, so it seems to be an issue of backward incompatibility.

Is it possible to work around it?

Answer (score 0):

Open the file ***".venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py"*** on line 473.

Add "***#***" in this line and it will be ok.